# "out of range" error inserting mobile number from servlet to SQL

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am trying to insert mobile number through prepared satement, but I am getting an error stating that type out of range even for Double type.

```
pstmt.setDouble(6, 9677627718);
```

How to insert mobile number from servlet to sql?

It says that out of range even for double data.

Comment: what is the type your mobile number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Telephone numbers" are not really numbers in the mathematical sense. They are just addresses (similar to email addresses) that happen to be composed of numeric digits. They do not need to be represented as numbers because typical numeric manipulations are not relevant. For example, it makes no sense to subtract one phone number from another.

Therefore you should store telephone numbers in your tables as strings, not as numbers. In particular, a common `int` (signed, 32-bit) could store the phone number `202-555-1212` (`2025551212` with the hyphens removed) but could not store `613-555-1212` because `6135551212` is too large to fit into an `int` column. (The largest "number" it could hold would be `214-748-3647`.)